# How to keep an item the same when window is resized

Tags: html, css

I'm kind of new to coding, so please be patient if this is a silly question. In my code, I have a little sidebar floated to the right, but I don't want it to shrink when I resize the window. For example, on Wikipedia articles, when you minimize or maximize the window, the information panel on the right stays the same size and the text on the left shrinks. How is this done in simple terms in HTML/CSS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either **too broad**, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a **specific**, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: could you display you code

Answer (score 0):

anytime your curious as to how someone did someone in html, you can inspect the webpage in your browser.  For instance, the information panel on wikipedia articles that sits on the right size of the article, is a table.  they set the width and margin and after doing so the table will not resize when someone resizes their browser.

```
<html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
            <table style="width:25.5em; border-spacing:2px;"></table>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use vw and vh instead of px or em and this will make the element has the same width and height based on screen resolution. you can use it like this

```css
.size{ width:45vw /* 45% of the size of window or screen */;
height:45vh /* 45% of the size of your current window size */
```

you can find more information here [a link](https://riptutorial.com/css/example/17657/vh-and-vw)